# Executable Crashes When Function is Run

Tags: c, avl-tree

I am creating an AVL for an assignment, but when ever I call the rotate right and rotate left functions the executable crashes with no error message. I think it might be due to a NULL pointer exception but I'm not sure.

Here is my code for the rotations:

```
TNODE *rotate_right(TNODE *y){

TNODE *x=y->left;
TNODE *t2=x->right;

x->right=y;
y->left=t2;

y->height =max(height(y->left),height(y->right))+1;
x->height=max(height(x->left),height(x->right))+1;
}

TNODE *rotate_left(TNODE *x){
TNODE *y=x->right;
TNODE *t2=y->left;

y->left=x;
x->right=t2;

y->height =max(height(y->left),height(y->right))+1;
x->height=max(height(x->left),height(x->right))+1;
}
```

And here is the insert function I call them in:

```
void insert(TNODE **rootp, char *name, float score){
    TNODE *np = (TNODE *) malloc(sizeof(TNODE));
    if (np == NULL) return;
    strcpy(np->data.name, name);
    np->data.score = score;
    np->height = 1;
    np->left = NULL;
    np->right = NULL;

    // 1. Perform the normal BST insertion
    if (*rootp == NULL) {
        *rootp = np;
         return;
    }

    TNODE *root = *rootp;
    if (strcmp(name, root->data.name) < 0 ){
       insert(&root->left, name, score);
    }
    else if (strcmp(name, root->data.name) > 0 ){
       insert(&root->right, name, score);
    }
    else return ;

    // 2. update height of this root node

    // add your code here
    root->height=height(root);

    // STEP 3: get the balance factor of this root node


    // add your code here
    int balance=balance_factor(root);

    // STEP 4: re-balance if not balanced

    // add your code here

   if(balance>1&&balance_factor(root->left)>=0){
       rotate_right(root);
   }
   else if(balance>1&&balance_factor(root->left)<0){
       rotate_left(root->left);
       rotate_right(root);
   }
   else if(balance<-1&&balance_factor(root->right)>=0){
       rotate_left(root);
   }
   else if(balance<-1&&balance_factor(root->right)<0){
       rotate_right(root->right);
       rotate_left(root);
   }

 }
```

The code runs fine if I comment out the last part where I have to rotate it so I'm quite sure the problem is there. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's not necessarily where the problem is. If you don't construct the tree properly in the first place, rotating it could run into problems.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to narrow down where the problem is? Also, tools like `valgrind` are useful for finding pointer use problems.[

Comment: sorry I'm newish to programming, do you know any debuggers I could use?

Comment: `gdb` is the usual debugger on Linux.

Comment: If you're using an IDE to write your code, it probably has a built-in debugger.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: thanks, I'm using notepad++ which I don't think has a debugger.

Comment: That's just a text editor, not an IDE.

Comment: How did your instructor teach you to debug programs? Do they just throw you to the wolves and hope you figure it out?

Comment: don't remember getting any advice on that, could be that I wasn't aying attention though.

Comment: Nah, from what I've gathered here, programming teachers just teach languages, they don't teach the process of programming. I'm just ranting....